# Docker-compose networks with Traefik

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to deploy three services with `docker-compose` and Traefik:

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --web --docker --logLevel=INFO
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.localhost"
      - "traefik.port=8080"

  db:
    build: ./db
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=example
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/db:/data/db
    restart: always
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"

  api:
    build: ./api
    environment:
      - DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=27017
      - DATABASE_NAME=example
      - HOST=localhost
    expose:
      - "1337"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.localhost"

  website:
    build: ./app
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:web.localhost"
```

The last container (`website`) is an static website build with `create-react-app` that consumes the API (`api`):

```
let response = await fetch(`http://api:1337/news`);
```

The problem is that the website is not able to resolve the host `http://api:1337` (i.e. by container name), but if I change that line to:

```
let response = await fetch(`http://<container-ip>:1337/news`);
```

Everything works perfectly. I tried to setup a network and it's not working either. Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can access containers with their names only from other containers.
If you change your react code to:

```
let response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/news', {
  headers: 'Host': 'api.localhost'
})
```

You should be able to access your container